# What is the limit for AWS SQS to pull messages from queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am trying to find what is the limit of messages that i can pull from sqs using lambda.
I saw some documentation from AWS that we can only recieve 10 messages at a time in the form of batch.
But my requirement is to pull 10-12k messages at a time from the sqs queue using lambda and loop through it.
Not sure this requirement is doable want to know if it is even possible.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html

Comment: Are you not triggering the lambda function using SQS trigger?

Comment: yes that is the plan

Comment: Then you don't need to worry about pulling the message from SQS. The lambda will be triggered whenever a message is available in the queue and the event will have the messages in it... Lambda functions are highly scalable and they will surely handle all the messages coming to the queue.

Comment: yes the plan is to trigger lambda function and read messages in batch.

Comment: Regardless of the method (pulling from Lambda, or SQS triggering Lambda), a maximum of 10 messages will be passed per request/invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the document from Amazon which is similar to your question [similar to your question](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-application-design-scaling-and-concurrency-part-2/)

> For example, a Lambda function receives messages from an SQS queue and writes to a DynamoDB table. It has a reserved concurrency of 10 with a batch size of 10 items. The SQS queue rapidly receives 1,000 messages. The Lambda function scales up to 10 concurrent instances, each processing 10 messages from the queue.

That means Lambda helps you to auto scale when you need to process a bunch of messages.

In this document, Amazon says that the concurrent executions [can be increased up to tens of thousands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html), **which I think it answers your question** but please be noticed that [the burst concurrency quotas is different from the regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html)

This one is the [real case example with Ebay API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/from-0-to-100-k-in-seconds-instant-scale-with-aws-lambda/)

For my real project, our practice is try to split the logic into smaller ones, which means we split into some smaller Lambdas and SQSs so that we can manage the logic, debug and also help to reduce the traffic.

And one thing you should also monitor is the price! Do not forget to monitor and consider for your solution.